# Is it possbile to translate text "AppName would like to Use your current location"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

My app uses GPS. At first launch, user is asked if he want's to allow gps positioning. I would like to translate this text to my language. Is it even possible?

Comment: Apple does this for you, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the device language to yours.

Comment: Yeah, that's something Apple should handle if it doesn't already. I would expect the text displayed to change based on the user's settings.